# Replace a word after a particular line using shell

Tags: json, shell, awk, sed, replace

I have the following  lines in json file

```
 {"name":"images",
 "enable":1,
 "binary_path":"/usr/bin/docker",
 "parameter":"images"
},
{"name":"pull",
  "enable":1,
  "binary_path":"/usr/bin/docker",
  "parameter":"pull httpd"
 },
```

I want to replace

```
"enable":1,
```

with

```
"enable":0,
```

of the json which has

```
"name":"pull"
```

I tried below codes

```
sed -i '/"name":"pull",/a "enable":0' test.json
```

Comment: use jq instead of sed/awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me -

Dry run -

`$ sed '/"name":"pull"/!b;n;c\ \"enable":0,' test.json`

Change in file with `-i` -

`$ sed -i '/"name":"pull"/!b;n;c\ \"enable":0,' test.json`

Output -

```
# sed '/"name":"pull"/!b;n;c\ \"enable":0,' test.json

 {"name":"images",
 "enable":1,
 "binary_path":"/usr/bin/docker",
 "parameter":"images"
},
{"name":"pull",
 "enable":0,
  "binary_path":"/usr/bin/docker",
  "parameter":"pull httpd"
 },
```

Answer (score 4):

The right way is to use particular *json* parsers like `jq`:

Sample `test.json`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "images",
    "enable": 1,
    "binary_path": "/usr/bin/docker",
    "parameter": "images"
  },
  {
    "name": "pull",
    "enable": 1,
    "binary_path": "/usr/bin/docker",
    "parameter": "pull httpd"
  }
]
```

---

```
jq '[.[] | if .name == "pull" then .enable=0 else . end]' test.json
```

The output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "images",
    "enable": 1,
    "binary_path": "/usr/bin/docker",
    "parameter": "images"
  },
  {
    "name": "pull",
    "enable": 0,
    "binary_path": "/usr/bin/docker",
    "parameter": "pull httpd"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can simply use the line operator in sed to achieve this. Try below,

`sed '/"name":"pull"/{n;s/.*/"enable":0,/}' test.json`

Add -i option to edit in the source file,

`sed -i '/"name":"pull"/{n;s/.*/"enable":0,/}' test.json`

Answer (score 2):

awk Solution

```
awk '/name":"pull/{a=1;print $0;next}a==1{$0="\"enable\""":""0" ;print $0;a=0;next}1  test.json
```